# What is the root mean square energy of a nucleon bound within a nucleus?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics

How does the root mean square energy of a nucleon in a  nucleus of atomic mass number A in the ground state  depend on A ?

Comment: Are you asking about kinetic energy or total energy?

Comment: Talking about total energy

Answer (score 3):

The energy of a nucleon in a nucleus is not an observable quantity (think about how you would measure it), and so is entirely dependent on the theoretical model used to describe the nucleus. Once nucleons are bound into a nucleus, they don't retain their individual identity. There is just "the nucleus". In principle, one can --with a suitably large computer--calculate properties of nuclei directly from quarks and gluons without ever making reference to protons and neutrons. 
With that said, a simple theoretical model is a fermi gas of nucleons. For a fermi gas, the kinetic energy goes like the density to the 2/3 power. As Lewis Miller pointed out, nuclei saturate and so the density is roughly constant and independent of mass number at 0.16 nucleons per cubic fm. This gives a kinetic energy on the order of 40 MeV, with a potential energy that roughly cancels it to give about 8 MeV per nucleon. Keep in mind that this is a model, and that all we can actually measure is the total energy of the system.

Comment: "In fact, one can --with a suitably large computer--calculate properties of nuclei directly from quarks and gluons without ever making reference to protons and neutrons. "  Maybe this will be true one day, but right now it is false.  The best that lattice QCD calculations can do right now is predict the properties of single neutrons and protons (and their mass difference has been successfully calculated only within the last year).  Calculations for the deuteron may be underway, but for heavier nuclei the situation if far beyond current capabilities.

Comment: Fair point. I edited my answer to say "in principle". The point is just to emphasize that the concept of nucleons in the nucleus is not required, but merely computationally convenient. Also this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5943 for example presents some attempts at calculating helium and the triton on the lattice.  I think most physicists expect that this can be done in principle. It's just a matter of technical implementation.

Answer (score 1):

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nucene/imgnuk/bcurv.gif

The answer to your question is contained in the curve linked above.

Details:  As can be seen from the binding energy curve, the binding (per nucleon) increases sharply as more nucleons are added at the lower mass numbers; it reaches a maximum at the Iron group (mass number near 56); and declines very slowly as the mass number A increases further.

This behavior is due to a phenomenon known as the Saturation of Nuclear Forces. Because the nuclear force between nucleons is short ranged, the addition of more nucleons to a large A nucleus does not result in tighter binding (which is the case for electrons in a large atom).  If the nuclear force were the only interaction felt by nucleons, then the binding per nucleon would become independent of A for large A. The long range electromagnetic repulsion between protons breaks this pattern and leads to the slow decrease in binding for large A. By the same mechanism, the binding at low A increases sharply in the low A range as the surface to volume ratio declines with increasing A.

Nuclei in their ground states are quantum in nature and like atoms exhibit a shell structure. At certain mass numbers, shell closures lead to enhanced binding in analogy to the noble gas atoms. For nuclei, these shell closure numbers are called magic numbers and their occurrence leads to the small scale variations in the binding energy curve.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Although the question is somewhat ill posed, it is nevertheless meaningful, and my answer responded in a meaningful way.  I assumed the interest was really in the average binding energy per nucleon as a function of A and the graph that I linked was precisely that.  Since the average binding is a very small percentage of the single nucleon rest mass, it is not too much of a leap to assume that a nucleus is a loosely bound assemblage of individual nucleons.  There are many experiments in nuclear physics that support this assertion.

Comment: In that context it is indeed helpful to respond, as you did, with quantities that are actually measurable. However, the original question suggested some confusion about what is and what is not measurable. Stated another way: if two theories made identical predictions for binding energies and reaction cross sections and differed only in their prediction of the energies of the constituent nucleons, no experiment can distinguish between them.